# Add number in map java

Tags: java

I am creating a function that loops through a string, separates it by comma and then takes the key from the second item in the array and the value from the 1st after splitting the string.

I then want to place these values in a map. This works perfectly, however if i have two strings with the same key it doesn't add the value up it just replaces it.

For example if my string was

```
123,totti 100,roma, 100,totti
```

I would want

```
totti 223
roma 100
```

Here is my code

```
private void processCallLogs(String[] splitCalls) {
    for (String individualCall : splitCalls) {
        int duration = 0;
        String[] singleCall = individualCall.split(",");
        duration += DurationParser.returnDuration(singleCall[0]);
        this.cost += CalculateCost.calculateCostPerCall(singleDuration);
        if (totalCallDurations.containsKey(singleCall[1])) {
            totalCallDurations.put(singleCall[1], singleDuration);
        } else {
            totalCallDurations.put(singleCall[1], duration);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `duration` and `singleDuration`?

Comment: nothing, i have taken it out

Comment: `duration` and `singleDuration` are both still in your code

Comment: @khelwood Agreed; this won't even compile anymore since `singleDuration` is used but not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the if with something like this:

```
if (totalCallDurations.containsKey(singleCall[1])) {
    duration += totalCallDurations.get(singleCall[1]);    
}
totalCallDurations.put(singleCall[1], duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a **map** and update the **value** if the **key** is present

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
myMap = new HashMap<>();
// 123,totti 100,roma, 100,totti
addToMap("totti", 123);
addToMap("roma", 100);
addToMap("totti", 100);
System.out.println(myMap);
}

private static void addToMap(String string, int i) {
int t = i;
if (myMap.get(string) != null) {
    t += myMap.get(string);
}
myMap.put(string, t);
}
```

Comment: Please do not use `myMap.get(string) != null`. Use `myMap.hasKey(string)` instead because depending on `null` can cause errors. Besides, `myMap` is out of scope in the function; how do you expect this to work? Please test your code before answering.

Comment: mymap in not declared in any of the methods i posted.. so scope is for sure there...

Comment: True... Sorry, I've been using Python so much that I thought you declared `myMap` in `main()`.

Comment: @AlexL. no problem :) and regarding the getKey(), I think there is no problem since the op will never put a null in the values...

Comment: Right, I suppose that is true. It looks bad to me though, but it will work perfectly fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, you can do this easily with the [`Map.merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method:

```
totalCallDurations.merge(singleCall[1], duration, Integer::sum);
```

Comment: would i need that in my if?

Comment: @pocockn You don't need an if with this. It will put your value and merge it with the existing one if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a map that will add the values together instead of replacing, I would recommend extending the `Map` type to make your own map. Since `Map` is very abstract. I would extend `HashMap`. (I suggest this both for code style and because it will make your code more extendable).

```
public class AdderMap extends HashMap<String, Integer> { // This extends the HashMap class
    public Integer get(String key) { // This overrides the Map::get method
        if(super.containsKey(key)) return super.get(key); // If the key-value pairing exists, return the value
        else return 0; // If it doesn't exist, return 0
    }

    public Integer put(String key, Integer value) { // This overrides the Map::put method
        Integer old_value = this.get(key); // Get the former value of the key-value pairing (which is 0 if it doesn't exist)
        super.put(key, old_value + value); // Add the new value to the former value and replace the key-value pairing (this behaves normally when the former value didn't exist)
        return old_value; // As per the documentation, Map::put will return the old value of the key-value pairing
    }
}
```

Now, when you initialize your map, make it an `AdderMap`. Then, you can just use `put(String, Integer)` and it will add it together.

The advantage of this solution is that it helps with keeping your code clean and it allows you to use this type of map again in the future without needing separate code in your main code. The disadvantage is that it requires another class, and having too many classes can become cluttered.